# looping and inserting rows in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very newbie in vba. I don't know how to loop and insert row(s). I have looking in Google, but many of them just show me loop in a selected/activated Range not that i want. This is my case :

I have a field exist in another sheet like this

```
month        value
4            300.000
1            120.000
5            1.500.000
```

I have new data that have a condition if months = 12 it will looping the month to 12 and divided the value / 12

```
month = 12
value = 12.000.000
result = 12.000.000 / 12 = 1.000.000
```

and the result will be continue from the last row like this

```
month        value
4            300.000
1            120.000
5            1.500.000
1            1.000.000
2            1.000.000
3            1.000.000
4            1.000.000
5            1.000.000
6            1.000.000
.
.
.
12           1.000.000
```

I have do in my code like this

```
Private Sub AddPostClick_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
    Dim i As Integer

    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    With ws
            If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
               .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = txtValue.Value
            End If

            If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
                For lRow = 1 To 12
                    .Cells(lRow + 1, 6).Value = txtValue.Value
                Next lRow
            End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

the problem is, this cell is not insert to the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below for finding the row after last row. Change the "range" to column -I think it is sixth column, "F"- in which you look in.

```
Dim lRange As Range

Set lRange = Worksheets("Sayfa2").Range("F1:F1000").Find(What:="*", _
SearchOrder:=xlRows, _ 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not lRange Is Nothing Then lRow = lRange.Row + 1
```

Comment: here I have change my code to click event. but when i insert new form. the rows replace the previous rows(not continue to from the last row)